# Avoid loop inside loop when using multiselect value as map key

Tags: apex, multi-select, loop

Have anyone face any issue when try to make multiselect as key before ? How to avoid for inside for for the case below?

Here the snippet:

```
 for(WorkSupport__c support :[select TypeSupport__c, Region__c from WorkSupport__c Limit 100]){

   system.debug('TypeSupport :'+support.TypeSupport__c);

   String[] types = support.TypeSupport__c.split(';');

   for(String str : types){
      map.put(str+'|'+support.Region__c,support);
   }



 }
```

Comment: A bit curious as to why would you need msp values as key? Wouldn't you have a scenario where may you have same value on the msp field and region field on different records, which in turn overrides any previous key that may have been added to the Map?

Comment: because it compare to other object that store data as non msp but need to compare with this record. can we focus whether that code above can be modified ? i m not going to rearchitecture the whole process soon.

Comment: Nested `for` loops aren't bad as such; they're only bad when they unnecessarily increase the computational complexity of the code or consume limits. Iterating over the values of a multi-select picklist is a pretty natural idiom for a nested `for` loop.